# how to weight imbalance class for ordered logistic classification machine learning

Tags: r, machine-learning, multiclass-classification, pls

I have a question about predicting wine quality (classic wine dataset from UCI). I use ordered logistic classification in PLSR after joining white and red in the same dataset. There are imbalanced numbers between white and red. I have tried SMOTE but it is not ideal, there is a lot of weight methods, which one should I choose? Thanks!!!! Any references will be fantastic!

Comment: Read this it may help [Class Imbalance-Handling Imbalanced Data in R](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2021/05/class-imbalance-handling-imbalanced-data-in-r/)

Comment: Is there any need to balance the data? https://matloff.wordpress.com/2015/09/29/unbalanced-data-is-a-problem-no-balanced-data-is-worse/